# Jquery how can i remove the class

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is my code and it is a single page website, when i click on toggle bar it displays my 'ul' and when i click on one of the 'a' it will take me to that div. I whant my toggle bar to close back automatically and i don't know how.

```
//HTML
<nav>
<div class="menu-icon">
    <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i> \\Toggle Bar
</div>
<div>
   <ul>
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
   </ul>
</div>
</nav>
//CSS
showing{
    max-height: 20em;
}

//Jquery
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menu-icon").on("click", function () {
        $("nav ul").toggleClass("showing");
});
});
```

Comment: create elements that match your selectors

Comment: thks it's works very well, but another solution for this you have, something more static not with a timer if you don't have any more ideas this will be great. Thks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong jQuery selector "nav"

`$("nav ul").toggleClass("showing");`

your HTML code doesn't have that, instead it has "div",  try:

`$("div ul").toggleClass("showing");`

and also fix your CSS:

`.showing {
    max-height: 20em;
}`

Comment: You gave me another answer with the right solution I don’t know why I can’t see it to respond you there, i whant to say thks